# How to checkout a nested folder as if was the root

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

I have a large legacy repo, of which I am only interested in the widgets directory.  By using a git sparse checkout I am able to download only the folder I am interested in, which is nice.
My local repo now looks likes this:

```
/.git
/blah/blah/blah/blah/widgets/foo-widget.f90
```

I would prefer to not see all that nesting.
Is there some variation on a sparse checkout whereby I could have my local repo look like this instead?

```
/.git
/widgets/foo-widget.f90
```

I am aware that I could just create a new repo, but then I would loose the ability push and pull from the remote repo.

Comment: This is not quite what you're asking, but a symlink is the first thing that comes to mind...

Comment: @joanis I looked at that but Im on Windows. As I understand it, symlinks are Linux only.

Comment: Yeah, the Windows concept is links is pretty weak. You can click on them interactively to get somewhere, but that's pretty much it, they don't behave at all like *nix symlinks so forget that idea...

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand it, symlinks are Linux only

No, they are available in Windows too. And since [Windows 10 Insiders build 14972 (2017)](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/), symlinks can be created without needing to elevate the console as administrator.

So once you have cloned your repo, you can add a symlink and work with the desired directory structure.